# getUserMedia alternative for iOS

Tags: iphone, html, camera, getusermedia, image-capture

Does anyone know if there are any (near) future plans to enable getUserMedia for Safari on iOS?

Secondarily, does anyone know of any work-arounds to access the camera from a standard mobile website on an iPhone?  I saw a post that referenced:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Can anyone confirm that this really works, and would I use this in lieu of getUserMedia, or would I do a browser/device detect first to determine if I should go the getUserMedia v. capture="camera" route?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure what you want, but I saw this javascript code that works, I mean it takes the picture.

```
 <script>
  $("#image-picker").change( function (event) {
  var files = event.target.files;
  if (files.length>0) {
  }
});
/script>

<input id="image-picker" type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

If you want to save, you got me there, I still don't know how to save the picture you take. Hope this helps you.