# Alternative to getUserMedia() for reading live camera stream on iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webrtc, getusermedia

We are building a mobile barcode-scanner using QuaggaJS that reads barcodes directly from the device's camera stream. Works fine on desktop/Android, but doesn't work at all on iOS.

From initial research, I've found that iOS simply does not support WebRTC/`getUserMedia` through Safari or iOS Chrome (related links below), which is what QuaggaJS uses to read the camera stream.

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659869/getusermedia-alternative-for-ios) about capturing a still image on iOS, but the answer provided is only for capturing a still image, not for reading the stream real-time.

**My question** - is there any other way to grab the stream from an iOS camera? Perhaps an alternate library other than QuaggaJS that does not use `getUserMedia`? I am not well-versed in Javascript, so I am not sure if there even is a possible way to access the camera stream other than `getUserMedia`.

A "no" is an acceptable answer here; I'm simply looking for someone more experienced to provide guidance.

---

Appendix/related links:

[navigator.getUserMedia alternative API for iOS safari mobile browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294422/navigator-getusermedia-alternative-api-for-ios-safari-mobile-browser)

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-navigator-getUserMedia-not-supported-in-Safari

https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-apple-or-microsoft/

[HTML5: getUserMedia iOS issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258597/html5-getusermedia-ios-issue)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*2017 update*: Apple just announced that getUserMedia will finally be supported in **iOS11**.

*Aug 2019 update*: ONLY works in Safari, not in a WebView of any kind. Thanks @Klathmon for the comment.

Comment: However it [ONLY works in Safari, not in a WebView of any kind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46717491/1724045). Don't get most of the way through an implementation only to have to scrap the whole project like I did!

Answer (score 5):

The quaggaJS page has a feature compatibility matrix which answers your question:

[image]

getusermedia is not supported on iOS safari.

As per the quaggaJS documentation (https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS#browser-support)

Quagga makes use of many modern Web-APIs which are not implemented by all browsers yet. There are two modes in which Quagga operates:

1. analyzing static images and
2. using a camera to decode the images from a live-stream. The latter requires the presence of the MediaDevices API. You can track the compatibility of the used Web-APIs for each mode:

   - Static Images
   - Live Stream

I would suggest that you use static image mode on iOS as live stream mode is not supported.

Comment: iOS no upgraded, iphone uesless with browser based growing application.
Android doign perfectly great job.

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: I mean, iPhone poor for getusermedia.

Comment: Getusermedia is from Webrtc which is heavily backed by google that's why safari isn't supporting the same. May be apple will create its own flavor.

Comment: Ya, apple is slow growing where google is fast adopiting. iPhone hold many issues for no reason.