# Livestream barcode reader - workaround for iphone with quaggajs? getusermedia not supported

Tags: javascript, html, quaggajs

Im trying to implement a live video barcode scanner feature into a rental app using Quaggajs. Got it working nicely to then discover that ios doesnt support web rtc. Does anyone know a good workaround or possible other solution? Only need the scanner to work from mobile devices. Cheers

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619598/alternative-to-getusermedia-for-reading-live-camera-stream-on-ios

Comment: Could be supported in the future: https://www.ifun.de/webrtc-apple-bereitet-den-safari-browser-vor-103363/